# Custom Webpart With checkbox

Tags: custom-web-parts

I Created Webpart Page in SPD and they saved inside site Pages then I chose Empty Date View.now I have Data list with some columns but they are not like Listview webpart, there is no Checkbox on each of row.

How to create(or enable) Checkbox in Custom webpart ?

Answer (score 0):

have you enabled "Allow individual item checkboxes" on the view?

[image: Edited listview]

Comment: That's for XSLT List View Web Part not Data View Web Part.
here you can read it.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/web-parts-for-views-and-forms-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-HA101805424.aspx#_Toc245608910

but I want this option for Data View Web Part.

Comment: Sorry.. too fast answer.. but why not use List view webpart?

Comment: because I can't use Filter Text for List view webpart,this Filter Gives only Exact Value.like this : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/92a89140-cabf-4df2-a59e-44c5d405bbb8/display-all-items-if-text-filter-webpart-value-is-empty?
In a xslt list view web part, you can only add a filter columnname contains Param1. This will only show items when an options is selected in the check box control.and this one http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=77